# Logic Pro X 10.5.1...Certain articulations won't make sound?

Tags: brass, logic-pro, trumpet, articulation

I'm trying to do a trumpet fall articulation, and it shows up as registering even in the piano roll, but when I play it, it's silent. What's going on?
[image]

Comment: Pure guess as I don't use Logic - your swing value could be taking your note on to before the last note off & is confusing the system. Try just moving it a tad later manually & see what happens.

Comment: I would check 2 things, first, does the first note overlap into the second? If so try shortening it. The other thing is it looks like the second note goes past the end of the region by a small amount. Try extending the region or shortening the second note a bit.